# How to stop Lumia phone syncing?

Tags: sync, contacts, lumia-520, microsoft-account, nokia-lumia-630

There are two Windows phones with the same Microsoft accounts. They have different contacts but I don't want the other phone's contacts. How can I stop contacts being deleted on phone 2 if deleted on phone 1 and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the only way to prevent this would be to, when you are adding a new contact, choose to save it to an account other than your MS account. (e.g. Your service provider may allow you to save contacts)